# Xamarin.Android automatic build on VS Team Service error

Tags: android, xamarin, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I set a continous integration environment with Visual Studio Team Service in order to build and publish Xamarin.Android application.

I have the following build process (which is the default one) :
[image]

I face an issue on the second step, Activate Xamarin license.
Here is a snapshot of logs sent by VSTS :

> Set workingFolder to default:
>   C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.101.2\tasks\XamarinLicense\1.0.16
>   [debug]agent.workFolder=C:\a [debug]loading inputs and endpoints
>   [debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_7D41EBCB-B0D7-43F1-AA0C-263B7D250D2B
>   [debug]loading
>   ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_7D41EBCB-B0D7-43F1-AA0C-263B7D250D2B_ACCESSTOKEN
>   [debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
>   [debug]loading
>   ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_7D41EBCB-B0D7-43F1-AA0C-263B7D250D2B
>   [debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION [debug]loading
>   ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION [debug]loading INPUT_ACTION
>   [debug]loading INPUT_EMAIL [debug]loading INPUT_PASSWORD
>   [debug]loading INPUT_PRODUCT [debug]loading INPUT_TIMEOUT
>   [debug]loaded 11 [debug]action=Activate [debug]email=foooo@foo.com
>   [debug]password=foooooo [debug]activateAndroid=null [debug]product=MA
>   [debug]timeout=30 [debug]action: Activate [debug]email: foooo@foo.com
>   [debug]product: MA [debug]activateAndroid: null [debug]timeout: 30
>   [debug]Login as foooo@foo.com [debug]Activate Xamarin license
>   [debug]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\mandroid.exe
>   arg: --datafile [debug]exec tool: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\mandroid.exe [debug]Arguments: [debug]
>   --datafile [command]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\mandroid.exe --datafile
>   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
>   [error]Failed to activate Xamarin license. {"code":-3,"message":"Could
>   not look up activation code."} [debug]task result: Failed
>   [error]Return code: 1

The most import part is the last one :

> [error]Failed to activate Xamarin license. {"code":-3,"message":"Could
>   not look up activation code."}

Of course I made sure that I have a correct free Xamarin account created on the official website.

How can I fix it ?
My application build correctly on my Win10 + VS2015 community

Comment: Do you have MSDN license??

Comment: Yes I recently get one. I haven't done any configuration to 'active' it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the "Xamarin License" step now. The build should can be finished successfully.

Comment: Activate and desactivate Xamarin licence is not required anymore to build Xamarin.Android application ?